# c# Windows Application failed to run on another computer

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, excel, office-interop

I have created an new C# windows forms application. I have added COM Reference "Microsoft Excel 15.0 Object Library" to my project. This project is for importing excel data to the dataset. I have done it. I works fine in my computer. If i run the exe file on another computer it showing error like below.

ERROR:

> Unable to cast COM object of type
>   Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.ApplicationClass’ to interface type
>   ‘Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Application’” This operation failed
>   because the QueryInterface call on the COM component for the interface
>   with IID '{{000208D5-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}' failed due to the
>   following error: Error loading type library/DLL (Exception from
>   HRESULT:0x80029C4A(TYPE_E_CANTLOADLIBRARY)).

Comment: (Re-)install Office on that machine.

Comment: If you use interop you should install the same MS Office version on the target machines.

Comment: Thanks @Dirk ,@Jaxedin so much,It solves my error,  If I want run my application to many systems,its not better way to installing the same office version to all those system.

Answer (score 0):

COM components are not my specialty, and I do not use them too often. But I will tell you what I have experienced before. Please note that I experienced this about 6 months ago and the circumstances were far from ideal at my work place.

In order to use a/some COM component(s) you also need to have it's dependency installed on the target computer (in this case Excel/Office). Have you checked if the target computer has Excel installed on it?

If not, you can use an OLEDB connection to read Excel files. I don't remember how this is done specifically.

Maybe this can help in some way to read Excel files using OLEDB: http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/705470/Read-and-Write-Excel-Documents-Using-OLEDB

Comment: Thanks for the response, but i need an answer using com reference (Microsoft Excel 15.0 Object Library) to access excel. The link you shared is quite helpful

Comment: As @Jaxedin said, you should have exactly the same Office libraries available in each computer your software will run. If you can't assure that, I suggest you use NetOffice http://netoffice.codeplex.com/ it is a smart wrapper to MS Office applications which allows you more relaxed conditions as long as you only use resources supported by all versions installed.

Comment: Thanks @VBobCat , U r suggestion is great, i hope Netoffice wrapper will solve my error. I'm gonna try this.

Answer (score 0):

In your proyect references, try to set Copy Local = true in your dll

Answer (score -2):

If you are working on a 64 bit development environment, try explicitly defining the use of non 32 bit version of the library. For doing so in visual studio, tick and then untick the box "Prefer 32-bit" in the build section of the project configuration, which will add `<Prefer32Bit>false</Prefer32Bit>` in the .csproj file.